# How to store coroutines inside a List?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I want to create a List of coroutines to start if future. How to store such functions inside a list?

Say we have a function like:

```
IEnumerator Example() {
    while (true) {
        yield return  new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

We cant store it inside something like `List<Func<IEnumerator >> list` but we get compiler error like:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Func<System.Collections.IEnumerator>>.Add(System.Func<System.Collections.IEnumerator>)' has some invalid arguments
```

when we call

```
           list.Add(Example);
```

or if we use `List<Example> list` we get no compile errors but on

```
            if (disposeActions.Any()) {
                yield return StartCoroutine(list[0]); //here we get null exception
                disposeActions.RemoveAt(0);
            }
```

So I wonder how to create a list to store IEnumerator functions and be capable to send its items to coutines?

Comment: hi myWallJSON, thanks for improving your question. I have voted to reopen the new version of the question, but you might also be able find your answer at http://answers.unity3d.com

Comment: +1 and reopen. I think it's interesting

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very difficult to understand, but maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
var listOfFunctions = new List<Func<T, TResult>>();
```